# Initializating an object with functional form actually does not call the default constructor

Tags: c++, object, instantiation

i'm trying to make a difference between different types of initializing objects. But I've read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)(middle to end of page) that if you try to call `Class object();` this will not instantiate an object, rather will define a function? I tried and it is so, but I don't understand why.

> `Circle c`;   // default constructor called
>
> `Circle c()`; // function declaration (default constructor NOT called)
>
> `Circle c{}`; // default constructor called

---

Here is how i tried to reproduce:

```
class Circle
{
    float r;
public:
    Circle()
    {
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
    }
    Circle(float r)
    {
        this->r = r;
    }
};
```

In `main()` I'm trying to instantiate an object like this `Circle c()` and it does not call the parameter less constructor. I was expecting seeing in console the message "default constructor". What does the syntax `Circle c()` does if it is not calling the default constructor? How is that a *valid function declaration*?

Comment: It's a function that takes no parameters and returns a Circle.  Look for "most vexing parse".

Comment: Try to declare a function called `c` that returns a `Circle` and takes no parameters.   Looks familiar, doesn't it?  Thus "most vexing parse".